# angularjs filter to compare words in string

Tags: angularjs, filter

If user selects busTye as "A/C" then I want to filter A/C buses from JSON :

Index.html :

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="type">Bus Type</label>
    <select name="busType" id="busType" ng-model="type">
    <option>A/C</option>
    <option>Non A/C</option>
    <option>Sleeper</option>
    <option>Semi Sleeper</option>
    <option>pushback</option>
    <option>MultiAxle</option>
    </select>   
 </div>

  <table ng-repeat="j in busDetails | filter: type:j.busType">
  <td>{{j.operatorName}}<br>{{j.busType}}</td>
  </table>
```

script.js :

```
   $scope.busDetails = {
    {
       "operatorName": "KPN",
       "busType"     : "2+1 Sleeper A/C"
    },
    {
       "operatorName": "KPN",
       "busType"     : "2+2 Pushback Non A/C"
    },
     {
       "operatorName": "KPN",
       "busType"     : "2+2 MultiAxle Volvo Semi Sleeper A/C"
    },
     {
       "operatorName": "KPN",
       "busType"     : "2+1 Sleeper Non A/C"
    }
    }
```

from this JSON, If I try to filter A/C bus I'm also getting Non A/C bus as result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more code, preferably a demo to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does work, when you fix your small errors in the code..
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5030/)

Your JSON is invalid, it should look like this:

```
$scope.busDetails = [{
    "operatorName": "KPN",
    "busType": "2+1 Sleeper A/C"
  }, {
    "operatorName": "KPN",
    "busType": "2+2 Pushback Non A/C"
  }, {
    "operatorName": "KPN",
    "busType": "2+2 MultiAxle Volvo Semi Sleeper A/C"
  }, {
    "operatorName": "KPN",
    "busType": "2+1 Sleeper Non A/C"
  }];
```

Also, the ng-repeat should not be on the table, but on the **row** :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="type">Bus Type</label>
    <select name="busType" id="busType" ng-model="type">
      <option>A/C</option>
      <option>Non A/C</option>
      <option>Sleeper</option>
      <option>Semi Sleeper</option>
      <option>pushback</option>
      <option>MultiAxle</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="j in busDetails | filter: type:j.busType">
      <td>{{j.operatorName}}
        <br>{{j.busType}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```